# How to set password guidelines in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, passwords

I am using Joomla 1.7 with Hikashop. That's why I want new registered users to have a secure password.
Is it possible to set password guidelines in Joomla, so that it isn't possible to register a user with a password like "12345" or "qwerty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that on clientside via additional Javascript or on serverside via an custom/extended authentification plugin.